Is There Any Way To Set A Custom Domain For Identity Center Verification Emails?
I am using AWS Identity Center with the default Identity Provider. While creating new users, AWS sends a verification email to allow the user to set up a password. My issue is that this email is considered to be a spam by our email anti-spam solution.
Since the email comes from AWS SES domain, allowing the entire domain is not an option for us. We use the Custom MAIL FROM feature for our identities in SES which allow us to prevent similar issues in our applications, is there any similar configurations change the sender MAIL FROM of the verification emails sent by AWS?
